# Statement with pointers appears to be missing an operator

Tags: c, pointers

I have encountered the following statement in C code and do not understand how to interpret it.

Recognizing the 2nd operand as a pointer reference (`*a`), it looks to me like the statement is missing an operator between the operands (interpreting `*` as pointer reference, not multiply).

I have run the code containing this statement, and it completes without errors, so I believe the statement is valid, but I just don't understand what its doing.

Here it is:

```c
val +=input_ptr[a] *filter_ptr[b];
```

Thank you.

Comment: C is a free-form language, where spaces doesn't matter. So `val +=input_ptr[a] *filter_ptr[b];` could be rewritten as `val += input_ptr[a] * filter_ptr[b];` which perhaps makes more sense?

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude points out, in this case `*` must be the multiplication operator for the statement to make any sense.

Comment: C syntax is defined in EBNF and so you can always figure out what a statement means. A token is formed by taking as many characters as will fit in the expected token (so '--' is always one token, never '-', '-'). Since what follows `input_ptr[a]` cannot be a unary dereference operator according to the syntax, it has to be a two argument multiplication operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two arrays: `input_ptr` and `filter_ptr`, you can get the value stored in those cells by doing, lets say, `input_ptr[0]` so :

**val** is increased with the value stored at index 'a' in array `input_ptr` multiplied by the value stored at index 'b' in array `filter_ptr`